# "Using" Clause Not working in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Migrating Oracle to Postgres 12 but don't know why I'm getting an error at the "USING" Clause. Sharing below the snippet of a query:

```
(SELECT
  'NPOS_PPV_SUCC' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  DONOR AS RNO,
  SENDER AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      SENDER,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND PORT.CREATED_ON BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND NPOS_PPV_SUCC_TIME IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      SENDER,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND PORT.CREATED_ON BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND NPOS_PPV_SUCC_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test1
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  DONOR,
  SENDER,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION
(SELECT
  'NPOS_PPV_FAIL' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  DONOR AS RNO,
  SENDER AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      SENDER,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND NPOS_PPV_FAIL_TIME IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      SENDER,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND NPOS_PPV_FAIL_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  DONOR,
  SENDER,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION
(SELECT
  'NPOS_APP_SUCC' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  DONOR AS RNO,
  SENDER AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      SENDER,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND PORT.CREATED_ON BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND NPOS_ANSWER_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND NOT (
        IS_START_FROM_NPOS = '2'
        AND NPO_STATUS = 'F_REJ'
      )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      SENDER,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND PORT.CREATED_ON BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND NPOS_ANSWER_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND NOT (
        IS_START_FROM_NPOS = '2'
        AND NPO_STATUS = 'F_REJ'
      )
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test2
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  DONOR,
  SENDER,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION
(SELECT
  'NPOT_NPOS_TRIG' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT AS RNO,
  DONOR AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND ORD_PPV_SUCC_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND IS_START_FROM_NPOS = '1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND ORD_PPV_SUCC_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND IS_START_FROM_NPOS = '1'
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test3
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT,
  DONOR,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
  'NPOT_NPOS_TRIG' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT AS RNO,
  DONOR AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND PORT.UPDATED_ON BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND IS_START_FROM_NPOS = '2'
      AND NPO_STATUS IN ('F_CAN')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND PORT.UPDATED_ON BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND IS_START_FROM_NPOS = '2'
      AND NPO_STATUS IN ('F_CAN')
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test4
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT,
  DONOR,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION
(SELECT
  'NPOT_PPV_SUCC' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT AS RNO,
  DONOR AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND ORD_PPV_SUCC_TIME IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND ORD_PPV_SUCC_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test5
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT,
  DONOR,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
  'NPOT_PPV_FAIL' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT AS RNO,
  DONOR AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND ORD_PPV_FAIL_TIME IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
      AND ':END_TIME'
      AND ORD_PPV_FAIL_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test7
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT,
  DONOR,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION
(SELECT
  'NPOT_APP_SUCC' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT AS RNO,
  DONOR AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND (
        '2' = '2'
        OR ORG_TRANSFER_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND (
        '2' = '1'
        OR NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND ORD_APPROVED_TIME IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND (
        '2' = '2'
        OR ORG_TRANSFER_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND (
        '2' = '1'
        OR NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND ORD_APPROVED_TIME IS NOT NULL
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test6
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT,
  DONOR,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION
(SELECT
  'NPOT_BIP' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT AS RNO,
  DONOR AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND (
        '2' = '2'
        OR ORG_TRANSFER_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND (
        '2' = '1'
        OR NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND NPO_STATUS IN ('BIP')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND (
        '2' = '2'
        OR ORG_TRANSFER_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND (
        '2' = '1'
        OR NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND NPO_STATUS IN ('BIP')
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test8
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT,
  DONOR,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
  'NPOT_SUCC' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT AS RNO,
  DONOR AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND (
        '2' = '2'
        OR ORG_TRANSFER_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND (
        '2' = '1'
        OR NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND NPO_STATUS IN ('SUCC')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND (
        '2' = '2'
        OR ORG_TRANSFER_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND (
        '2' = '1'
        OR NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND NPO_STATUS IN ('SUCC')
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test9
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT,
  DONOR,
  AREA_CODE)
UNION
(SELECT
  'NPOT_SUCCP' AS TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT AS RNO,
  DONOR AS DNO,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND (
        '2' = '2'
        OR ORG_TRANSFER_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND (
        '2' = '1'
        OR NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND NPO_STATUS IN ('SUCCP')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      DONOR,
      RECIPIENT,
      AREA_CODE
    FROM
      TBL_PORTORDER_HISTORY PORT,
      TBL_PORTSUBSCRIBER_HISTORY SUB
    WHERE
      PORT.RID = SUB.NPO_RID
      AND NPO_TYPE = 'TER'
      AND (
        '2' = '2'
        OR ORG_TRANSFER_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND (
        '2' = '1'
        OR NPO_SUBMIT_TIME BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'
      )
      AND NPO_STATUS IN ('SUCCP')
      AND PORT.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
      AND SUB.PART_KEY IN (15, 16)
  ) as test7
GROUP BY
  TOTAL_TYPE,
  RECIPIENT,
  DONOR,
  AREA_CODE)
USING
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME,
        l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME, l_START_TIME, l_END_TIME
        ;
```

Getting error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 44:   USING TOTAL_TYPE
```

Can anybody help me with this? I'm stuck with it for the last 2 days. Without **USING** clause, the query is working fine but with **USING** I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: Is this your complete query?

Comment: Please share your complete query, so that can identify the issue. I see there is no joins in the query

Comment: @JimMacaulay I have updated the complete query. the value of l_start_time and l_end_time is initialized in the procedure.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name migrating it to Postgres 12 and now you would be able to see the placeholder in query

Comment: You need to replace the placeholders with the actual variable, so instead of `BETWEEN ':START_TIME'
        AND ':END_TIME'` you have to use `BETWEEN l_start_time AND l_end_time`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have already tried the query by using the actual variable and by using the value of start_time and end_time directly but the problem is with USING clause only....query is executing fine

Comment: Obviously you need to remove the USING clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the suggestion but I would like to know , will removing the USING clause impact the existing query in any way or it will the same result as it gives in oracle?

Comment: Maybe you need ( ) around the column list following using, if I read the documentation of postgress right "T1 { [INNER] | { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [OUTER] } JOIN T2 USING ( join column list )" in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-table-expressions.html

Comment: @AlexFunk have tried that already

Comment: @AlexFunk: the USING clause passes parameter values in the PL/SQL code. It is not used for a JOIN condition in the above code

Comment: @user10221025: well, obviously removing the USING will impact the existing query, because it will make it work, rather then resulting in an error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, thank you for your immediate support

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you help me fix out the below error?
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "P0002"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function cnp."pkg_upc$upc_exist"(text,text,double precision,timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone) line 15 at assignment
SQL state: 22P02


I'm calling procedure as call cnp."pkg_upc$exist"(
 'abc',
 'c',
 123,
 '20201003',
 '20201003')